# Load different index files for different customers in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I want to be able to host different index.html files for my different customers so I allow customer branding on the app-loading screen.

My customers have their own urls, such as:

```
customer1.myapp.com
customer2.myapp.com
```

So each customer wants their own app-loading screen (You know the default "Loading...".

I really prefer not having this configuration in a script tag in index.html, and load different preloading screens based on `location.origin` or something similiar, but that's all I can think of at the moment.

Any ideas how to solve this? Loading different index.html files came to my mind but have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Your hosting / domain provider allows to redirect each subdomain to different folder, so you can just point it to another index.html

Answer (score 0):

Different domain names imply different builds for each domain.

This means you should have several configurations for your `angular.json` file (you know, like when you use `--prod`).

By default, you have development and production. But you can add as much as you want.

Good thing is, the configuration takes into consideration file replacement :

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [{
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }],
```

This means that all you have to do, is provide the files you want to replace in your configuration !

After that, all you have to do is run `ng build --configuration=clientOne`, and your project will be built for your client One, with the correct files in it.